# MessageDialog title is coming 'Not Responding'

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am performing a long running operation and showing message dialog as "fetching details" and closing the same once the operation is performed.

```
try{
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(), "Information", null, "Fetching Details...", MessageDialog.NONE , new String[] {}, -1);
dialog.setBlockOnOpen(false);
dialog.open();
//Schedule long Running operations

} finally{
  dialog.close()
}
```

If the operation takes more time, dialog is showing not responding (Title changes to "Information (Not Responding)").

How can avoid the not responding status ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not run long operations in the UI thread. Doing so will block the thread until they finish and the UI will become unresponsive.

Run your operations in a background thread, or an Eclipse Job or even a Java 8 CompleteableFuture.

Use the `Display` `asyncExec` in your background code to update the UI as required.

Another alternative is to use `ProgressMonitorDialog`:

```java
ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell);

try {
  dialog.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
    @Override
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
      monitor.beginTask("Task name", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);
      try {
        // TODO your long running code
        // TODO check monitor.isCanceled() as often as possible
      }
      finally {
        monitor.done();
      }
    }
  });
} 
... catch exceptions
```

Comment: Thanks Greg! I used ProgressMonitorDialog approach to solve my issue.